# Python, BeautifulSoup, iMAP and Requests

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, imap

I am writing a program that scrapes emails and retrieves links from specific emails like Newegg. I can login using iMAP and get the html coding, however whenever I actually find the html code in BeautifulSoup, the href isn't an actual link. The code below is what I'm using.

```
for part in email_message.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == "multipart":
        continue
filename = part.get_filename()
    if not filename:
        ext = '.html'
        filename = 'msg-part-%08d%s' %(counter, ext)
        counter += 1
    content_type = part.get_content_type()
    print(content_type)
    if "html" in content_type:
        html_ = part.get_payload()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.prettify())
```

I found my specific 'a' element that I need, but the information is completely scrambled.

```
<a 003e40bf801121da0c8026371fac2881d7ada96d0f3044bd52ea90c6f133482b7ac302="A6D66F63B93C9324A61A7BF6F53C6AD3B9FCE2E9722F2737F5C2BDEEC024FDB8BB1A8A=" 2='55);"' 255,="" 300px;="" 6035c14bccf6122e13d0c10420388428d9f6da5e55d8c39a946196846f58cb49754b4b="624023C5DA52531A16144B86B446AD159FC1B545111C71DA86A4B2BAB81E3BC6809F33=" a1c0a2d2231e3aa2c54f352a6ead95f6a0d3cad4f9d4610f9475ac"="" block;="" c41a281473fd50144612e9e4807a3c31920713f3fa05e6e851e830e5aaed502d2057db="5696E077EDBD8839ED7D1D9DFE6BCF861A354D0E6FB52F0818DB4C7971AB53C7F73CBB=" color:="" decoration:="" display:="" hre='f=3D"https://www.newegg.com/mr/DAC2DEFCF7F955FE4BCD7E3DF4926A74/D1F70B=' none;="" rgb(255,="" style='3D"text-=' target='3D"_blank"' width:="">
Verify My Email
<img 2018="" 6px;"="" :="" border='3D"0"' icon_arrow.='png"' images="" neemail="" promotions.newegg.com="" src='3D"https=' style='3D"width:' transactional="" width='3D"6"'/>
</a>
```

And this is what the actual html looks like if I were to extract it with inspect elements.

```
<a href="https://www.newegg.com/mr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style="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.newegg.com/mr/DAC2DEFCF7F955FE4BCD7E3DF4926A74/D1F70BC41A281473FD50144612E9E4807A3C31920713F3FA05E6E851E830E5AAED502D2057DB5696E077EDBD8839ED7D1D9DFE6BCF861A354D0E6FB52F0818DB4C7971AB53C7F73CBB003E40BF801121DA0C8026371FAC2881D7ADA96D0F3044BD52EA90C6F133482B7AC302A6D66F63B93C9324A61A7BF6F53C6AD3B9FCE2E9722F2737F5C2BDEEC024FDB8BB1A8A6035C14BCCF6122E13D0C10420388428D9F6DA5E55D8C39A946196846F58CB49754B4B624023C5DA52531A16144B86B446AD159FC1B545111C71DA86A4B2BAB81E3BC6809F33A1C0A2D2231E3AA2C54F352A6EAD95F6A0D3CAD4F9D4610F9475AC&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1641074397136000&amp;usg=AOvVaw0KGbJN7dTvHZEejpneFiwb" xpath="1">
Verify My Email
<img border="0" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/_AqrkZlchXMl0NMIJmmpeVH9ePljKIfp9UFOSxeynkr2vxupXQV1LDQqi3y8DDhGWlAfsZ0hZ8VKMRBhrnDFeeqT6rZsn3ypYcFKSEgx_gSfxIUYFJJfeS1JHxetYJiOYA=s0-d-e1-ft#https://promotions.newegg.com/NEemail/transactional/images/2018/icon_arrow.png" style="width:6px" width="6" class="CToWUd">
</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't my href actually come up as the Newegg link? I can take bits and piece of the one I get from BeautifulSoup and descramble it, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

I need to be able to get the link in order to run requests on that link.

Comment: try my lib https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Change this

```
html_ = part.get_payload()
```

To this

```
html_ = part.get_payload(decode=True)
```